# Get Element Value With Ordinal and Condition in XML

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I'm trying to loop through my XML using JavaScript testing for 2 conditions in the XML. Since the XML is being traversed in an archaic and customized version of JavaScript, I need to refer to the XML using ordinals. Here is a sample of my XML. I want to get the current ID number from the XML where IsSelected = false.

```
    for(var x = 0; x < nCount; x++){
     if( SCRIPT_REFERENCE_TO_XML("/OptionalEquipment/EquipmentOption" + " 
       [" + x + "]/[IsSelected = 'false']")){
        removeRecs[x] = 
          SCRIPT_REFERENCE_TO_XML.getValue("/OptionalEquipment/EquipmentOption" + "[" + x + "]/@vehicleOptionId");
     }


            <OptionalEquipment>
            <EquipmentOption vehicleOptionId="7093735">
              <DisplayName>4-Cyl, GDI, 2.4 Liter</DisplayName>
              <VehicleOptionId>7093735</VehicleOptionId>
              <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
              <OptionTypeDisplayName>Engine</OptionTypeDisplayName>
            </EquipmentOption>
            <EquipmentOption vehicleOptionId="7093790">
              <DisplayName>Auto, 6-Spd Shiftronic</DisplayName>
              <VehicleOptionId>7093790</VehicleOptionId>
              <IsSelected>true</IsSelected>
              <OptionTypeDisplayName>Transmission</OptionTypeDisplayName>
             </EquipmentOption>
            <EquipmentOption vehicleOptionId="7093801">
              <DisplayName>FWD</DisplayName>
              <VehicleOptionId>7093801</VehicleOptionId>
              <IsSelected>true</IsSelected>
              <OptionTypeDisplayName>Drivetrain</OptionTypeDisplayName>
             </EquipmentOption>
            <EquipmentOption vehicleOptionId="7093804">
              <DisplayName>AWD</DisplayName>
              <VehicleOptionId>7093804</VehicleOptionId>
              <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
              <OptionTypeDisplayName>Drivetrain</OptionTypeDisplayName>
            </EquipmentOption>
            </OptionalEquipment>
```

I'm not sure how to use an ordinal with a condition.

Comment: What is `SCRIPT_REFERENCE_TO_XML` ? And is the platform not a normal browser?

Comment: Yes, that's platform specific code.

Answer (score 0):

In a modern browser it could look like this:

```js
var XML = `<OptionalEquipment>
            <EquipmentOption vehicleOptionId="7093735">
              <DisplayName>4-Cyl, GDI, 2.4 Liter</DisplayName>
              <VehicleOptionId>7093735</VehicleOptionId>
              <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
              <OptionTypeDisplayName>Engine</OptionTypeDisplayName>
            </EquipmentOption>
            <EquipmentOption vehicleOptionId="7093790">
              <DisplayName>Auto, 6-Spd Shiftronic</DisplayName>
              <VehicleOptionId>7093790</VehicleOptionId>
              <IsSelected>true</IsSelected>
              <OptionTypeDisplayName>Transmission</OptionTypeDisplayName>
             </EquipmentOption>
            <EquipmentOption vehicleOptionId="7093801">
              <DisplayName>FWD</DisplayName>
              <VehicleOptionId>7093801</VehicleOptionId>
              <IsSelected>true</IsSelected>
              <OptionTypeDisplayName>Drivetrain</OptionTypeDisplayName>
             </EquipmentOption>
            <EquipmentOption vehicleOptionId="7093804">
              <DisplayName>AWD</DisplayName>
              <VehicleOptionId>7093804</VehicleOptionId>
              <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
              <OptionTypeDisplayName>Drivetrain</OptionTypeDisplayName>
            </EquipmentOption>
            </OptionalEquipment>`
var oParser = new DOMParser();
var oDOM = oParser.parseFromString(XML, "application/xml");
var opts = [...oDOM.querySelectorAll("IsSelected")]
  .filter(node => node.textContent === "false")
  .map(notSel => notSel.previousElementSibling.textContent);

console.log(opts)
```